# Measurement of the retention period of a memory cell

Tags: non-volatile-memory, flash-memories

Manufactures of Non Volatile memory devices give a quote for the **Memory retention** period of their device.

To the best of my understanding, this period refers to the maximum period up to which the information stored on the device is guaranteed to be retained without once powering up the device.

This retention period is usually in the range of a few years. How are these long confidence periods running into decades calculated?

I am aware of the effects in memory cells like capacitor leakage, transistor degradation and change in threshold voltage of transistors that could contribute to the corruption of memory. But I don't think the interaction of these effects can be modelled accurately enough to come up with these retention period numbers.

Comment: Look up Arrhenius. Originally for chemical reaction rates, it applies to any simple thermally activated process, like memory cell leakage.

Comment: @Neil_UK thanks for reminding me about the Arrhenius Equation. But would transistor degradation processes like the dielectric breakdown, DIT trap formation and entering of free charges inside the Dielectric be covered under the simple thermal activation energy model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by "artificial aging".

The devices are exposed to high temperature and voltage for months on end. 
Batches are removed from running and are tested at increasing time intervals.